# search documents on the basis of matching fields and length in array - Elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document structure like bellow in elasticsearch,

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'abc',
  post: [{
    type: 'text',
    url: '__url___'
  }, {
    type: 'image',
    url: '__url___'
  }, {
    type: 'text',
    url: '__url___'
  }, {
    type: 'video',
    url: '__url___'
  }, {
    type: 'text',
    url: '__url___'
  }]
}
```

And I want to search on documents that have posts with `type` as `text` appearing more than two times. Is it possible in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

You need to use a [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-scripting.html#_source_field) for this type of search, for a field called `post` and a sub-field called `type`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_source.post.type.count(param1)>2",
          "params": {
            "param1": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And make sure you [enable inline scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in your configuration file:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```

**Option 2**

This operation can, also, be done at indexing time to save some time when searching, using a `transform`. Something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "transform": {
        "script": "if(ctx._source.post.type.count(param1)>2) ctx._source['count_texts']=ctx._source.post.type.count(param1);",
        "params": {
            "param1": "text"
          }
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "count_texts": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
...
```

Making sure you enable the proper scripting settings in the configuration file:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.mapping: on
```

And, at search time, a query like this should do it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "count_texts": {
            "gte": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage of `transform` is that the heavy script operation is performed at indexing time, rather than at search time and potentially the search is faster than when using the script at searching time.

The disadvantage of `transform` is that you cannot actually specify a different value for `param1` unless you define another `transform` in the mapping itself. Meaning, what if you want to count `video`s as well? You need to add another `transform` and another field `count_videos` for example.